# Google Scripts Concatenate Cells in different columns

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have the following scenario where I want to concatenate cells in different columns but the quantity of columns differs from case to case.

example1: In cell A2 there is the value of **70286** & and the cell B2 there is the value of **playmobil**.
**The end result in F2 should be +70286 +playmobil**

example2: In cell A4 there is the value of **70666**, in the cell B4 there is the value of **lego** and in the cell C4 there is the value of **ninjago**.
**The end result in F2 should be +70666 +lego +ninjago**

[image: example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solutions:

**Google Sheet Formula:**

You can use [TEXTJOIN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7013992?hl=en) and if you want a plus sign in front of the string you can use [CONCAT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093592?hl=en) to add it.

Use this formula in column F:

```
=CONCAT("+",textjoin(" +", 1, A2:E2))
```

[image: example]

If you don't know how many columns you want to use, then you can select the full row:

```
=CONCAT("+",textjoin(" +", 1, A2:2))
```

---

**Google Apps Script:**

- We get the data of the second row as a 2D array using [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues).
- Then we apply [flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) to convert it to 1D.
- The next step is to remove the empty cells by using [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).
- Finally, we use [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to get the final string as the sum of all strings.

The logic can be easily adjusted. You can do this logic for multiple cells etc.

**Code snippet:**

```
function myFunction() {
  const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const row = 2;
  const data=sh.getRange(row,1,1,sh.getMaxColumns()).
                   getValues().
                   flat().
                   filter(c=>c!='').
                   reduce( (a, b) => `${a} +${b}`);      
  const result = `+${data}`;
  sh.getRange('F1').setValue(result);
  Logger.log(result);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately I want this as a code, for script editor. Also in your example you use A2:E2, but in my full sheet I don't always know how many columns I need to concatenate

Comment: If you don't know how many columns do you have then simply remove `E`. Therefore use this: `=CONCAT("+",textjoin(" +", 1, A2:2))`. @GeorgeChalikiopoulos

Comment: @GeorgeChalikiopoulos If you want a script solution, then you need to be more specific. Where exactly do you need to put the output data? what is the range of the input data? Do you want a predefined or a dynamic input? But I don't see any benefit having a google script for something that is quickly achieved by a simple formula.

Comment: @GeorgeChalikiopoulos I added a code snippet in javascript (GAS) if you want to take a look.